# Flutter: showing one dialog at a time

Tags: flutter

I am fairly new to state management in Flutter, and I have an application where the user will be interacting with dialogs, and a dialog may have a button to open another dialog which can result in the following:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBSzr.png

As shown, multiple issues arise when more than one is opened at once --  most notably the previous dialog is still visible in the background. So when a user opens a new dialog, is there any method where I can hide the dialog behind it, and when the frontmost dialog closes, show the previous one which is hidden? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Navigator.pop(context);` method to close the dialog on your button's `onPressed` before opening the second dialog.

And then while closing your second dialog you can reopen your previous dialog.

Example:

```
showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text("Hello World"),
          content: Text("This is content"),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);  //Close your current dialog
                  //TODO:open your second dialog
                },
                child: Text("Open"))
          ],
        );
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first try to re-think the logic for opening multiple dialogs at the same time.

Maybe there is a quick workaround for that, but if you keep adding more and more dialogs, then it would become a mess.

Since `showDialog<T>` function returns `Future<T?>`, you could potentially use `await` and wait until the first dialog is closed and then open the second one and so on:

```
bool canContinue = await showDialog<bool>(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => YourWidget(),
          );
```

Alternatively, you could pop by using `Navigator` but as said, this will be visible to the user that something weird is going on (pushing and popping dialogs programatically).